# return id of inserted record in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I created stored procedure to insert data and I want to get the id of inserted record in same procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `dbname`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp1`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp1`(
    Cname VARCHAR(30),
    Camount INT(10)

)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user(    Username,    PAmount    )
VALUES(    Cname,    Camount)    ;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS pid FROM user;
```

but this cause error in next query

error : 
    `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.

From here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 0):

If the id is declared as a primary key , make use of last_insert_id() function which will resolve the issue. For more details refer to last_insert_id() in mysql documentation

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id